# Setting the right foreign key on insert

Tags: sql-server-2005

Morning all,

I'm doing a lot of work to drag a database (SQL Server 2005, in 2000 compatibility mode) kicking and screaming towards having a sane design.

At the moment, all the tables' primary keys are `nvarchar(32)`, and are set using `uniqId()` (oddly, this gets run through a special hashing function, no idea why)

So in several phases, I'm making some fundamental changes:

1. Introducing ID_int columns to each table, auto increment and primary key
2. Adding some extra indexing, removing unused indexes, dropping unused columns

This phase has worked well so far, test db seems a bit faster, total index sizes for each table are MUCH smaller.

My problem is with the next phase: foreign keys. I need to be able to set these `INT` foreign keys on insert in the other tables.

There are several applications pointing at this DB, only one of which I have much control over. It also contains many stored procs and triggers.

I can't physically make all the changes needed in one go.

So what I'd like to be able to do is add the integer FKs to each table and have them automatically set to the right thing on insert.

To illustrate this with an example:

Two tables, `Call` and `POD`, linked `pod.Call_ID -> Call.Call_ID`. This is an `nvarchar(32)` field.

I've altered call such that `Call_ID_int` is identity, auto increment, primary key. I need to add `POD.Call_ID_int` such that, on insert, it gets the right value from `Call.Call_ID_int`.

I'm sure I could do this with a BEFORE trigger, but I'd rather avoid this for maintenance and speed reasons.

I thought I could do this with a constraint, but after much research found I can't.  I tried this:

```
alter table POD
add constraint
pf_callIdInt
default([dbo].[map_Call_ID_int](Call_ID))
for Call_ID_int
```

Where the `map_Call_ID_int` function takes the `Call_ID` and returns the right `Call_ID_int`, but I get this error:

> The name "Call_ID" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions
>   are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks very much in advance!

-Oli

Comment: I'm missing something: how do you expect the database to know the id of the `CALL` that corresponds to the parent of the new `POD` record that you are inserting, unless you tell it yourself?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted to achieve with the scripted "default", if it were possible - an (unchanged) POD insert would hit the DEFAULT constraint, which would look up Call.Call_ID_int using POD.Call_ID/Call.Call_ID and set POD.Call_ID_int.

Comment: Or to put it in a much easier way after re-reading this... POD and Call are already linked on Call_ID (nvarchar(32)).  I am introducing new columns to Call and POD - Call_ID_int (int) and want to somehow set POD.Call_ID_int to the right thing on insert without changing every single SQL INSERT on POD.  This will let me gradually change my SELECTs later to use Call_ID_int, which should be a much faster join.

Comment: I see, I did not realize it's a temporary solution that you are planning to phase out. I'm upvoting the answer about triggers - they appear to be the best place for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are the easiest way.

You'll have odd concurrency issues with defaults based on UDFs too (like you would for CHECK constraints).

Another trick is to use views to hide schema changes but still with triggers to intercept DML. So your "old" table no longer exists only as a view on "new" table. A write to the "old" table/view actually happens on the new table.

Comment: Thanks gbn - I'll probably bite the bullet and do it with triggers then :-)

Comment: @Oli Comber: that's how I'd do it